# Why is "${1:-}" necessary?

Tags: bash

I'm a little confused after reading this simple bash function:

```
log_daemon_msg() {
    if [ -z ${1:-} ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    echo $@
}
```

According to `man 1 bash`, which says:

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> ```
>    Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is
>    substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
> ```

If `$1` is NULL or unset, the value of `$1` is NULL. This is where my confusion comes from: why it is necessary to assign $1 a NULL value even if the fact `$1` is NULL or unset is already known? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the function works, but not for the expected reason. If `$1` is empty, it disappears completely, since it isn't quoted. The command run by the shell is `[ -z ]`. Now `-z` is not an operator, but simply a non-empty string, which `[ ... ]` evaluates as true, and so the test succeeds and the body of the `if` statement is executed. The "correct" code is `if [ -z "${1:-}" ]`, which will always treat `-z` as an operator, even when the argument expands to an empty string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible reason is to be compatible with `-u`, a useful shell flag that
signals an error whenever a variable/parameter is unbound.

```
$ set -u
$ echo ${1:-}

$ echo $1
bash: $1: unbound variable
```